# How to define function accepting curried function parameter?

Tags: scala

Below `fn2` failed to compile,

```scala
def fn(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
def fn2(f: ((Int)(Int)) => Int) = f
fn2(fn)(1)(2) // expected = 3
```

How to define `fn2` to accept `fn`?

Comment: Please don't just say "failed to compile" but also give the compiler error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be as follows:

```
scala> def fn2(f: Int => Int => Int) = f
fn2: (f: Int => (Int => Int))Int => (Int => Int)

scala> fn2(fn)(1)(2)
res5: Int = 3
```

`(Int)(Int) => Int` is incorrect - you should use `Int => Int => Int` (like in Haskell), instead. Actually, the curried function takes `Int` and returns `Int => Int` function.

P.S. You could also use `fn2(fn _)(1)(2)`, as passing `fn` in previous example is just a short form of eta-expansion, see [The differences between underscore usage in these scala's methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27732549/1809978).