# How to specify function parameter with implicit?

Tags: scala

I would like to pass a function with signature

```
def insert(o: Role)(implicit s: Session): UUID
```

into a function (as `inserter`) with signature

```
def insertRows[T](instanceList: List[T], inserter: T => UUID): Unit
```

How do I specify that `inserter` has an implicit `Session`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should find out how to make a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) from method, that requires implicit:

```
scala> def a(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) = a
a: (a: Int)(implicit b: Int)Int

scala> a _
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter b: Int
          a _
          ^ 
//I assume you can't specify implicit before `a _`, otherwise you have your answer anyway :)

scala> a(_: Int)(_: Int)
res18: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

Then, it becomes clear what to pass:

```
scala> def f(f: (Int, Int) => Int) =0
f: (f: (Int, Int) => Int)Int

scala> f(a(_: Int)(_: Int))
res16: Int = 0
```

Or even:

```
scala> f(a(_)(_))
res25: Int = 0
```

For any other curried function [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239677/how-to-define-function-accepting-curried-function-parameter/26239730#26239730) works. I hope one day scala will became smart enough to support same way for implicits.

P.S. In your specific case:

```
 def insertRows[T](instanceList: List[T], inserter: (T, Session) => UUID): Unit

 insertRows[Role](list, insert(_)(_))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify that `insert` uses an implicit. Only requirement is that there should be an implicit value available while using it.

```
implicit val s = new Session(...) // or import if defined elsewhere.
insertRows(list, insert)
```